# My radio buttons don't change to Checked when clicked. I'm trying to use this to change the content displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I'm making a really basic weather app using an API. There's a part of my code in which I want the user to click a radio button of the location for which I will display the current weather. I then have a function in JavaScript that checks if the radio button is checked. If it is, it will display the weather for that location. The trouble I'm having is that this doesn't appear to work when the user clicks the button and only works if I manually change the HTML to 'checked="true"'.

Any ideas how I can get the html to change to 'checked="true"' when the user clicks the button?

```js
function success(pos) {
  if (manchester.checked) {
    var lat = 53.48;
    var long = -2.24;
    weather(lat, long);
  } else if (leeds.checked) {
    var lat = 53.80;
    var long = -1.5491;
    weather(lat, long);
  } else if (london.checked) {
    var lat = 51.5074;
    var long = -0.12;
    weather(lat, long);
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label for="manchester">
      <input type="radio" value="manchester" id="manchester" name="location" checked>Manchester</input>
     </label>
  <label for="leeds">
      <input type="radio" value="leeds" id="leeds" name="location">Leeds</input>
     </label>
  <label for="london">
      <input type="radio" value="london" id="london" name="location">London</input>
     </label>
</form>
```

The following function works if I manually change each radio tag to be 'checked="true"', however I want this just to happen when the user clicks the radio button.

Comment: <form action="">
     <label for="manchester">
      <input type="radio" value="manchester" id="manchester" name="location" checked>Manchester</input>
     </label>
     <label for="leeds">
      <input type="radio" value="leeds" id="leeds" name="location">Leeds</input>
     </label>
     <label for="london">
      <input type="radio" value="london" id="london" name="location">London</input>
     </label>
    </form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```js
const manchester = document.querySelector('#manchester')
const leeds = document.querySelector('#leeds')
const london = document.querySelector('#london')
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]')
for (let i = radios.length; i--;) {
  radios[i].onclick = success;
}

function success(pos) {
  if (manchester.checked) {
    var lat = 53.48;
    var long = -2.24;
    console.log(lat, long);
  } else if (leeds.checked) {
    var lat = 53.80;
    var long = -1.5491;
    console.log(lat, long);
  } else if (london.checked) {
    var lat = 51.5074;
    var long = -0.12;
    console.log(lat, long);
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label for="manchester">
      <input type="radio" value="manchester" id="manchester" name="location" checked>Manchester</input>
     </label>
  <label for="leeds">
      <input type="radio" value="leeds" id="leeds" name="location">Leeds</input>
     </label>
  <label for="london">
      <input type="radio" value="london" id="london" name="location">London</input>
     </label>
</form>
```

If something is unclear - I will explain.